# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, intellij-idea

This issue is happening on IntelliJ but it's fine in Eclipse.
I have the correct version on ChromeDriver with my Chrome browser, which is v.83 for both

This is the code apparently giving the issue:
[image]

And this is in my pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.slackspace/openkeepass -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.slackspace</groupId>
    <artifactId>openkeepass</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```